# JS - Вложенный транзитивный экспорт модулей

Tags: javascript

Файл B.js включает: `export * from 'C.js';`.

Файл C.js включает: `export { func1, func2 };`

Будет ли корректной следующая форма записи в файле **A.js** и будет ли она включать все экспортируемые модули из файла C: `import { func1, func2 } from 'B.js';`

Comment: что значит _будет ли экспортироваться функция в A.js и C.js?_

Comment: @Grundy , согласен - исправил текст вопроса.

Comment: да, таким подходом иногда пользуются создавая index.js, и делая в нем export для всех файлов в папке, потом при использовании достаточно указать путь до папки, а не до конкретного файла

Comment: @Grundy , именно для этого я это и использую, просто уточняю если оба файла делают экспорт *, то будет ли это работать транзитивно. Можете ответить и Я закрою вопрос. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, данная форма записи корректна и будет включать все экспортируемые модули, за исключением `export default`.

Судя по справке, такая запись называется [Module Redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Module_Redirects).

Для того, чтобы перенаправить все export исходного модуля *вместе с default* можно воспользоваться следующей записью:

```
// module "redirect-module.js"
export {default} from './other-module';
export * from './other-module';
```

Answer (score -3):

Добрые день!

File `C.js`

```
const mult = (a, b) => a * b;
const sum = (a, b) => a + b;

export default { mult, sum };
```

File `B.js`

```
import * as helpers from './C';
export const { mult, sum } = helpers;
```

File `A.js`

```
import { mult, sum } from './B';
```

Comment: что должен показывать данный ответ? В чем отличие от примера в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy В примере, который описан в условии вопроса, неверное использование `export *`. Такой конструкции нет, но есть `import *`. В примере, который я привел - рабочий код, который решает задачу из первоначального вопроса. Подробнее про импорты тут - https://learn.javascript.ru/modules#import.

Comment: Вот пример похожей дискуссии https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640696/es6-module-syntax-is-it-possible-to-export-as-name-from

Comment: строка номер 13 в описании синтаксиса: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Syntax

Comment: плюс описания в [спецификации](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports) начиная с шестой редакции, а сейчас уже 9

Comment: @Grundy виноват, беру слова обратно!

Comment: кстати по ссылке на enSO немного другая проблема.

Comment: @Grundy там просто писали, что `export *` в стадии пропоузала.

Comment: не export, а именно `export * as`. Про который либо забыли либо не подумали :)